# Nginx adding new site's subdomain takes no effect

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean, nginx-config

I have a VPS on digitalocean that works great with five subdomains. But when I decided to add 6th (RC), it doesn't work. In order not to make mistakes, I made the following:

1. duplicated existing (working) /var/www folder and renamed into `rc`
2. changed rights to this folder `sudo chmod -R www-data:www-data rc`
3. duplicated working config in `etc/nginx/sites-available` and renamed it to `rc`
4. changed `server_name` and `root` rooting there. So, it looks like so:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        charset UTF-8;

        server_name rc.myserver.com;
        root /var/www/rc;
        index index.html;

        location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
```

5. created symlink with `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/rc /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/rc`
6. restarted nginx: `sudo service nginx restart`

Now my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` folder looks so:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Jul 21  2019 html -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/html
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Jul 19  2019 hunt -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/hunt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Dec  2 16:43 monit -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/monit
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Feb  1 13:57 rc -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/rc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Jul 21  2019 rent -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/rent
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Jul 20  2019 tools -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/tools
```

`sudo netstat -plutn | grep nginx` shows:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      29155/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      29155/nginx: master
```

My `nginx.conf` has this code lines active:

```
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

`/var/log/nginx/error.log` and `/var/log/nginx/access.log` didn't show any problems.

But when I try to get rc.myserver.com - I get "Failed to open the page" safari message:
`Safari can’t open the page “http://rc.myserver.com” because Safari can’t find the server “rc.myserver.com.”`

What's the problem can be with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you point your subdomain to the **Droplet ip-address** ?

first thing you've to do is to point your subdomains to the single ip address via your **DNS provider (A, CNAME).**

I think that's why you are getting error:

```
Safari can’t open the page “http://rc.myserver.com” because Safari can’t find the server “rc.myserver.com”.
```

[image]

point `rc.yourserver.com` to Droplet IP address :)

Comment: you are right! It helped. I don't know why but I thought that if I point  "main" domain name to my droplets ip, it should work for all subdomains )))